# 'Field never assigned error" message meaning

Tags: java, class, android-studio

What does the error message 'field never assigned' mean and how can you assign the field. I wanted to know for the sake of learning so I can learn what it means and how to assign so I won't get this error again.

```js
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;


 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
```

How would I assign in this one for example

Comment: Why is your code enclosed in a JavaScript code block? It won't run!

Comment: @DerGolem I couldn't find anywhere else to put it and I'm kinda new to stackoverflow so I wasn't sure where to put it. I thought that javascript was the closest thing to the java class. For future reference where can I put it so it runs?

Comment: **IT WILL NEVER RUN**. Simply select your code and press `Ctrl` + `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply means you are trying to use (say assign) a field which you never initialized. For e.g.

```
.. mymethod() {
    int a;
    ..
    int b = a;
    ..
```

Now since you never assigned/defined a, you cannot assign a to b. Hence compiler will complain as you see now.